# Buzzing noise after replacing my output jack

Tags: repair

I have a bass with active electronics. My output jack broke and I replaced the jack with the brand output the company recommended. After replacing the jack I get a intermittent buzz/interference noise. My question is could I have damaged either the wire or the active electronics.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Was the new socket a switched socket? On active basses, the circuit is turned on when a jack plug is inserted. If not, the battery may have drained. Otherwise the soldering may have not taken properly, resulting in a dry joint. Doubtful that the electronics are damaged - you did remove the battery first, I hope.

Comment: Yes it is. Spector recommended changing with a switchcraft brand barrel output jack. I made sure I knew what wires went were and also took a picture of it before I started. I removed the battery and changed the jack but the whole time I was worried about ruining the active electronics. I also put a fresh battery in after I was done.

Comment: Can you tell by looking at the solder joint if it is a dry solder joint? Should I take it a part and re solder the jack.

Answer (score 2):

If you used a soldering iron, not a blowtorch, the electronics are probably o.k. Soldering is a bit of an art. Tin the wire, tin the tags, then you only need enough heat to re-melt the solder, put them together, and keep still till it's solidified. There may be a stray strand of wire that is catching a wrong terminal/tag.

Comment: Flux is a big help, since it helps to conduct heat quickly, try to get the electronics type, as the plumbing type is often conductive (and potentially corrosive I think). Not a big problem if you wash the circuit after.

Comment: Note electronics solder usually has a flux core, but separate flux can be useful for tinning large metal leads on components.

Comment: @Yorik - especially dirty and corroded ones. I love flux - Gradum, etc...